# Checkbox list in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

Is there any module in Orchard CMS that I can install to get a checkbox list? I checked in the gallery but could not find one. If there is none, is there is a workaround this?

I want to associate a product item with multiple categories (fixed set of categories).

Thanks!

EDIT :

I checked the Taxonomy module as per the suggestion. Now, I want to access the terms in the view. I have seen some posts where they can access it using
    `(IEnumerable<Contrib.Taxonomies.Models.TermPart>)Model.Terms`

Using shape tracing, I am trying to figure out how to access the terms. My model doesn't have any terms field! I can access my custom type (Project) which has 'ProjectCategory' as Taxonomy Field. But there is no mean to view/select terms from there.

See attached screenshots. [image]

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: What happens when you try `(IEnumerable<Contrib.Taxonomies.Models.TermPart>)Model.Terms`?

Comment: I can't access that either. I have attached some screenshots.

Comment: That's all the help I can provide, I have limited experience with Taxonomy field. I thought you had trouble accessing the Taxonomy field itself but it seems you can access the field, but not the terms through the field. That may or may not be possible, you might want to look through the Taxonomy code or ask in the Contrib.Taxonomies board on codeplex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to access the terms the following way :

```
IEnumerable<TermPart> assignedTerms = _taxonomyService.GetTermsForContentItem(contentItemId, "NameOfTaxonomy");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a module specifically for checkbox lists, but it sounds like the Taxonomies module might be what you're looking for. You can add a Taxonomy field to your product content type, and define a Taxonomy for that field that contains all your categories.

Once you do that the editor page for your products will have a checkbox list (or radio select if you allow only one in the taxonomy field's settings) for the "Categories" taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for. Can we make that a mandatory field?

Comment: I just tested it. How can we access the contents ( Categories selected in the Taxonomy field) in the View?